# Loading xib to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a xib with is a collectionView.

I want to load the xib so i use this code

```
HomeCustomCollection* myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCustomCollection" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

after loading i set xib

```
frameTemp.size.width = screenWidth;
```

screenWidth = the size of the screen. Mine is 320 width but when i go to the view is smaller than the 320 that i have set that

Can you tell me what could be/ is the problem or the reason to that?

Thank you!!

EDIT: this is the code that's used at the time

```
   HomeCustomCollection* myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCustomCollection" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];



            frameTemp = myViewObject.frame;
            //frameTemp.origin.y = rows * 1000;
            frameTemp.origin.y = (rows * (userRows * 100 + 60));
            frameTemp.size.height = userRows * 140;
            frameTemp.size.width = screenWidth;
            myViewObject.frame = frameTemp;
```

FIXED IT:
instead of

```
   frameTemp.size.width = screenWidth;
```

i've put this

```
   frameTemp.size.width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

Don't know why but now is working.
Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes I am. Is that a problem?

Comment: Show the line where you calculate screenWidth (and what device is this)

Comment: #define screenWidth [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width

iPhone 5s

Comment: You are setting `myViewObject.frame = frameTemp;`, right ?

Comment: Yes I am. this already worked with another view but this time, i can't make it work

Comment: It's fixed, thanks anyway guys

Comment: Using `Autolayout` is a solution, not a problem...

Comment: Off topic suggestion: use a reference to your object in IB, so that you don't need `myViewObject` nor `objectAtIndex`, but a property which will be populated in `owner` during `loadNibNamed`.

Comment: Auto layout isn't a problem but combining it with setting explicit sizes can be.